# KeyCloak Where the jti claim is stored?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to study about **Preventing Replay Attack** that keycloak provided, I think it use jti claim to handle it

First I logged in via openid RESTAPI (...protocol/openid-connect/token) it return JWT like this

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJlX0l1RWo2cWEza2ZMb1MyVUwyNGJUMGJKUElXRWRkU3YxM2RSd1ZTM1lzIn0.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.OZnw3SbaBpVJSN1KbHMcdmP-zt55AIxmBv3ddyvfXEV-zqStH_TkmZ6P36oDoKu-UctGb9KdemmO0EHM0z1tN4vk35WtS5K3luWtYv42FWvx67mifUxc9BCsgXPz4qx78Kd05UzQ6297NqAAiDfU8gdeywT3mNZ_2AoT45Sw5Sb1cCq8pAJokOHT2PSLHGgTYpY6wbSKe9msfchmzJv1FZK1RnLuLY9HwDhbn_VDIgWlmro8bXNq5eTLAVtnzEL2vEokeFdKDlnPfoBk1oPE5XfjVaqoSBo5yxwxPMKDX_g4EayOXHjQqRCTTKdZm3Ah14DN0t8XBWi3p2vdUhqoIA",
    "expires_in": 59,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI3ZTVmNzhhYy05ODVmLTRjMTgtYmMwYS1kMDJjZDFlOGRhNGQifQ.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.Hsaib16poW3SW0EYUB80jU0HyseZi_Ui9tj_2QJAZ-w",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 1566975958,
    "session_state": "6bde39df-7adf-405e-8ca1-0b749aae07d5",
    "scope": "profile email"
}
```

access_token decoded you will see **jti claim**

```
{
  "jti": "6f178d12-4377-4931-99c8-ebb24959f76b",
  "exp": 1566977393,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1566977333,
  "iss": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/master",
  "aud": [
    "master-realm",
    "account"
  ], 
 ...
```

Next I will see new session list on admin as image below
[image]

Second I use access_token to get userinfo RESTAPI (.../protocol/openid-connect/userinfo) it return response like this

```
{
"sub": "49100abd-4dac-4934-950b-97b4dc1bb90c",
"email_verified": false,
"name": "superadmin superadmin",
"preferred_username": "superadmin",
"given_name": "superadmin",
"family_name": "superadmin",
"user": {
    "deviceId": []
},
"email": "superadmin@gmail.com"
}
```

When I click Logout all sessions on backoffice ,jti is deleted on storage and I get userinfo again it return

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "User session not found or doesn't have client attached on it"
}
```

Where the jti claim is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTI claim value is just a random UUID which is stored nowhere. What you are looking for is `session_state` param which is the session ID. When you pass `access_token` to `/userinfo` endpoint Keycloak retrieves `session_state` value and searches for the corresponding session in the distributed cache (Infinispan).

After you click on `logout all sessions` button Keycloak clears all the sessions in the cache.

**UPDATE**

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#compromised-access-and-refresh-tokens

> Another thing you can do to mitigate leaked access tokens is to shorten their lifespans. You can specify this within the timeouts page. Short lifespans (minutes) for access tokens for clients and applications to refresh their access tokens after a short amount of time. If an admin detects a leak, they can logout all user sessions to invalidate these refresh tokens or set up a revocation policy. Making sure refresh tokens always stay private to the client and are never transmitted ever is very important as well.

There is more information about security considerations on the link above.

**Token Blacklisting**

There is no such a thing as Token Blacklist in Keycloak and it should not be. Tokens are issued on behalf of the user or service account for particular client. So If you want to give a regular user access to some service protected by Keycloak you just create this user in Keycloak Admin Console. For third-party apps in machine-to-machine communication you create a client with service account enabled and third-party app uses its client_id and secret to issue access and refresh tokens on behalf of itself.

Instead of blacklisting a token you just logout (delete from the cache) user's or client's session.

If you want to completely remove your partner's access to API you can just disable client (admin -> clients -> client -> set enabled to false) or user (admin -> users -> user -> set enabled to false).

Comment: JTI not use for blacklist token? and openid auth endpoint (RESTAPI) create a session?

Comment: What is token blacklist in Keycloak? Yes, each time a user is authenticated, Keycloak creates session and issues access/refresh tokens pair for this session. I added a link to the relevant documentation section.

Comment: OK it's clear for session. JTI is created by keycloak but not used? Can you read this https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/blacklists-vs-grants

Comment: @PanupongKongarn I updated my answer. In short, instead of blacklisting a token you just logout certain user's (or service account's) session.

Comment: OK last question how about device management in keycloak (logout by device .. iphone,samsung)?. it not supported?

Comment: I didn't find anything about device management in Keycloak. You can extend authentication mechanism to include user agent information and display it on account's sessions page or even create custom REST endpoint which will log out every session for specific device.

Comment: Hello what is the device field on credential table?